# filter out elements not containing search string [have solution, looking for improvement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK this was hard to describe in a title. 
What I have is an input field and three paragraphs [will refer to them as 'Ps']

```
<p>ABCD</p>
<p>CDEF</p>
<p>XYZ</p>
```

now when a button is pressed in the input field the paragraphs that do not contain the search string get filtered out `hide()`. Done with the following:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var x = $(this).val();
    $("p:not(:contains('" + x + "'))").hide();
});
```

when backspace or delete is pressed the Ps that do not contain the search string get shown again `show()` like this:

```
$("input").keydown(function(){
        var x = $(this).val();
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

        if( key == 8 || key == 46 ){
            $("p:not(:contains('" + x + "'))").show();
        }
});
```

Now this causes a weird behavior. I'm really bad at explaining this..
To get what I am talking about follow these steps in this [fiddle result](https://jsfiddle.net/zkcekygL/4/embedded/result/)

1. click into the input field
2. type 'abc' [immediately after typing 'a' the last two Ps are hidden]
3. type 'x' [so the input is now 'abcx' and the first P has been hidden]
4. press backspace AND PAY CLOSE ATTENTION [all the Ps are shown for a split second and after that only the first on stays as intended]

Here's the [full JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkcekygL/4/)

**So, what I would like to know is if there is anyway to not have all the Ps shown for that split second, and just have the first P displayed when backspace is pressed.**

Comment: So when you delete `x` from `abcx`, what you expect your output to be?

Comment: oh snap, didnt know that exists. i figured if you can answer your own questions to share knowledge it  wouldn't be a problem here.. but i will probably repost it there tomorrow if this doesn't get answered.

Comment: @void what it is. the first paragraphs, but without the other two showing for like 500ms.. I forgot to say that in the question, I just added it in the bold at the bottom. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
        var x = $(this).val();
        $("p:not(:contains('" + x + "'))").hide();
        $("p:contains('" + x + "')").show();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/zkcekygL/6/)

Comment: wooow. I don't know why I made it so hard for myself.. I get that the split second was cause by the two functions sorting it out between themselves, but now I don't even know why I went through the backspace solution.. this is just so simple and logical.. thank you. will accept your answer in 5 minutes

Comment: Consider a slight variation, using `JSON.stringify()` to quote and escape the string; otherwise things will go wrong if the `input` contains `'`. Quote-accepting version: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/rORpwL

Comment: @PaulRoub Nice pick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is because on keydown you have

```
$("p:not(:contains('" + x + "'))").show();
```

Which says for every p that does not contain my text, **show it**.

And then on keyup, for the same key, you have

```
$("p:not(:contains('" + x + "'))").hide();
```

Which says for every p that does not contain my text, **hide it**.

I believe

```
$("p:not(:contains('" + x + "'))").show();
```

Should be

```
$("p:contains('" + x + "')").show();
```

Void's answer is correct for consolidating your code and does also fix your issue, however this explains where the problem was in the code you posted.

Comment: True true. it was the two functions sorting it out between themselves causing the 500 display of all the Ps.. but when I remove the `:not` like you suggested it does't work at all then.

Comment: @Cream [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfmsvtvf/) this works for me. The event being fired is always one key outofdate because on keydown the key hasn't actually been registered until the end of the event but it doesn't _not_ work.

Comment: oooh, my bad. That was actually why I went for the backspace solution, I was trying to fight the key not being registered yet, totally forgot about that... my bad. thank you :)